# How to query: Array does not contain (case insensitive) element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to retrieve documents where the tags **array** does not contain an element ignoring case sensitivity.

I'm using the inverse of my array contains query:

```
.find({"tags":{"$regex": "^(?!someTag$)", "$options": "i"}})
```

However this returns also returns documents where there's a tag that isn't "someTag".

Comment: There's a operator called `$nin` that can help you.    
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

Comment: @igorkf that would've been the solution if it wasn't for the case insensitivity

Comment: Maybe this helps:   
    
`db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "-someTag", $caseSensitive: false } } )`

Comment: Please provide sample docs & required o/p..

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by a colleague:

Adding a simple $not does the trick.

```
.find({"tags": {"$not": {"$regex": "^(?!someTag$)", "$options": "i"}}},{"tags":1})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `array does not include` behavior with the not equal `$ne` operator, and case insensitivity with a [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/index.html#collation).

Consider a collection with several tags:

```
> db.coll.find({},{_id:0})
{ "tags" : [ "Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3" ] }
{ "tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ] }
{ "tags" : [ "TAG4", "TAG3", "TAG5" ] }
{ "tags" : [ "tag4", "tag6", "tag7" ] }
```

`$ne` can be used to exclude exact matches:

```
> db.coll.find({tags:{$ne:"tag3"}},{_id:0})
{ "tags" : [ "Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3" ] }
{ "tags" : [ "TAG4", "TAG3", "TAG5" ] }
{ "tags" : [ "tag4", "tag6", "tag7" ] }
```

With the addition of a collation, the `$ne` match can be case insensitive:

```
> db.coll.find({tags:{$ne:"tag3"}},{_id:0}).collation({locale:"en",strength:1})
{ "tags" : [ "tag4", "tag6", "tag7" ] }
```

Note that in order to use an index with this query, you will need to create an appropriate index with the same collation.